# Sharepoint inherited Property

Tags: power-automate, default, property, automation

I have a custom column in SharePoint with employee number. I want everything placed into a folder (That contains a non null value) to automatically inherit the employee number in the custom column from said folder. This way I would only need to set the property on the employee folder rather than each file.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the purpose of the "Document Set", a built-in feature of SharePoint (for both on-premise and online). This [article](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/08/create-document-set-in-sharepoint-online-step-by-step.html) could be useful to learn about it.

For example, you can create a new document set called "Employee" with a column "EmployeeID". Every document stored in the document set will inherit the value of EmployeeID (the value will be stored at the level of the document set).